# Is there a way to set up an ODBC DSN to an Access accdc backend database?

Tags: ms-access, crystal-reports, odbc

I split an Access 2013 database (accdb) against which I had previously created an ODBC System DSN, and then used Crystal reports to write reports (i'm more comfortable with Crystal 2011 than Access reports).
Now, after the database is split, I get a message of 
Logon failed.
...Could not find file '(unknown)'.
I tried setting up a different ODBC DSN but, when you do that, the only file options for Access are mdb or accdb extensions.
I've also tried renaming accdc file to accdb but that fails as well.

Any suggestions or direction appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you split an access database base the backend gets a different name eg db_be.accdb. Make sure that you are using the name for the backend when linking from crystal report

Answer (score 0):

Access itself cannot using ODBC to consume a back end. Now that you split the database, you have to re-link Crystal reports to the new back end. So if you had

```
myApp.Accdb
```

you now have

```
myApp.Accdb   (the front end)
myApp_be.accdb   (the back end)
```

So your Access front end does not have the tables, but only links to tables. Access thus does NOT use ODBC but has a internal linking mechanisum. In fact, while  your Access front  end from above can link to any ODBC source such as SQL server, an all kinds of ODBC sources, the front end CAN NOT and DOES NOT support ODBC to a Access back end (it simply not allowed).

You thus have to now re-link (point) crystal reports to above new back end file.

So while the existing myApp.accdb will continue to work as normal, you cannot point Crystal reports to the front end as linked to linked tables is not allowed.

Comment: apparently, I must have split my db with access 2010.  I looked at your response and went in, and see that the file name selection when you split just has the accdb file extension.  Before, you could split and save as and accdc extension (for the backend), and, at the same time, create the executable ( accde extension).  It looks like I'll have to take the existing backend database file, rename to a different accdb file, then open and import the queries and forms, then re-split using access 2013.